# Create bootable USB flash drives

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, usb, software-rec

I want to create some bootable USB flash drives as per below.

1. Windows 10 Legacy BIOS (MBR) Bootable MS-DOS 6.22 USB Flash Drive that boots up to a DOS prompt, has access to MS-DOS commands including Diskpart and can access a non-bootable computer HDDs.
2. Windows 10 UEFI (GPT) Bootable MS-DOS 6.22 USB Flash Drive that boots up to a DOS prompt, has access to MS-DOS commands including Diskpart and can access a non-bootable computer HDDs.
3. Windows 10 Legacy BIOS (MBR) Bootable Windows 10 USB Flash Drive that boots up to a menu to include various System Utility Tools: MiniTool Partition Wizard, Hirens BootCD etc and even MS-DOS if that is possible. Then we can ignore 1 above.
4. Windows 10 UEFI (GPT) Bootable Windows 10 USB Flash Drive that boots up to a menu to include various system Utility Tools: MiniTool Partition Wizard, Hirens BootCD etc and even MS-DOS if that is possible. Then we can ignore 2 above.

I have researched the internet and have tried some programs including rufus, Universal-USB-Installer, YUMI, Partition Guru but still only having little success in doing so.

I am also a bit confused with some of the programs steps involved in creating a bootable disk and copying MS-DOS and programs to the USB.

I have had partial success in creating a bootable DOS USB Flash Drive with rufus and PowerISO MS-DOS IMAGE that boots up the USB Flash Drive to its DOS Prompt but I do not have access to any DOS commands

I also have had partial success in creating a bootable USB Flash Drive with YUM-Multiboot USB Creator and loaded MiniTool Partition Wizard. MiniTool Partition Wizard appears in the Multiboot folder of the USB but does not show up in the USB BOOTUP MENU.
I have tried several times in the above attempts but still no joy…

Could someone please direct me to the best software to create the above bootable USB Flash Drives (1-4) and explain (in simple terms) the various steps involve if the software description steps are a bit vague.

Comment: For #3, [Hirens BootCD PE](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/) would be what you're looking for, as it's WinPE with a GUI and all the tools from Hirens BootCD in Menu format

Comment: Please note that software recommendation requests are specifically off topic on this site. You can see that noted in the helper text for the tags you chose, and in the Help section you were referred to when you posted your first question here.

Answer (score 3):

Before anything else, **Diskpart is not a MS-DOS program.** It's a Windows program that only happens to be a console program, but it does most of its job by talking to the Windows "Virtual Disk Service" and you will *not* get it running on MS-DOS 6.22.

At the same time, MS-DOS 6.22 cannot access NTFS-formatted filesystems, nor can it access GPT-partitioned HDDs, nor even partitions larger than several GB… and it *really* won't be able to boot on pure-UEFI systems (BIOS was practically the "device driver" for MS-DOS so it's not optional), so USB stick #2 is not actually possible to make.

So there is no point in explaining the creation of USB sticks #1 or #2 – practically the only systems where MS-DOS would have been useful as a recovery tool were systems old enough that they didn't have USB (or didn't support booting from USB).

Instead, use a regular Windows "install" USB drive – it has Diskpart (and DISM) included if you press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> to access Command Prompt, **and** you can have a single USB stick that will boot on both BIOS and UEFI systems. (The official Windows "Media Creation Tool" will do this; Rufus also has a hidden "cheat code" to enable dual BIOS/UEFI support – it's mentioned in the [Hiren's BootCD docs](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/usb-booting/).)

As for USB sticks #3 and #4, I'll probably defer to the Ventoy suggestion in the other post.

(Modern versions of Hiren's BootCD are apparently based on WinPE – the exact same WinPE that powers the Windows "Setup" – so it should in theory be possible to merge the two into a single USB stick by just adding a second .wim file via `bcdedit`. I have not tried doing this.)

Answer (score 2):

Although you list many multi-boot tools, you don't give any details
as to the problems you have encountered with them, which makes it
impossible for us to correct the errors.

Perhaps it would be simpler to use
[Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html) :

> Ventoy is an open source tool to create bootable USB drive for
> ISO/WIM/IMG/VHD(x)/EFI files.
> With ventoy, you don't need to
> format the disk over and over, you just need to copy the
> ISO/WIM/IMG/VHD(x)/EFI files to the USB drive and boot them
> directly.
> You can copy many files at a time and ventoy will give
> you a boot menu to select them (screenshot).
> You can also browse
> ISO/WIM/IMG/VHD(x)/EFI files in local disks and boot them.
> x86
> Legacy BIOS, IA32 UEFI, x86_64 UEFI, ARM64 UEFI and MIPS64EL UEFI are
> supported in the same way.
> Most types of OS supported
> (Windows/WinPE/Linux/ChromeOS/Unix/VMware/Xen...)

[image]